# Dynamic Block View

Tags: 7, views

I'm trying to create a **Block View** to display a second node's **Body** based dynamically on the node currently being displayed.

Example: node/1 is currently being displayed, and the block in the sidebar loads the body (Contact information for example) of a secondary node, say node/12. But if node/2 is being displayed, the block will instead load the Body of an entirely different node.

Can I create an integer field in the Content Type that identifies the secondary, "Contact Block", node to display, and how would I create the View to use this field? Or do I need to create a relationship, and if so, which Content Type needs the relationship, the primary node, or the secondary node?

Comment: Assuming D7, if you use one of the reference modules, eg https://www.drupal.org/project/references or https://www.drupal.org/project/entityreference, that will/should simplify things as Views most probably won't think that an integer field is actually a node id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EntityReference was what I was looking for and I found a good walkthrough here: http://www.wunderkraut.com/blog/overview-of-entity-reference/2011-10-11

Comment: did you need to use a php filter?

Comment: Shouldnt need php filer, should be able to filter on content type nid in contextual filters.